# JWT Refresh токен как его обновлять в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, token, jwt

Как обновлять refresh token на сервере и клиенте (React)???
Я просмотрел какое-то количество статей и вопросов, но абсолютного ответа не увидел, есть только пару вариантов:
1 - Отправлять токен через промежутки времени (или когда время действия access токена подходит к концу. Eсть ли советы как или чем это лучше сделать?)
2 - Менять токен при каждом запросе к серверу, как мне кажется это будет напрягать сервер и непонятно как реализовать изменение токена ведь или придётся мудрить на сервере или делать несколько запросов)

Мои технологии в проекте:
клиент(axios, redux, redux-saga sockets.io)
сервер(express, passport, socket.io)

Надеюсь что мой на мой вопрос ответят и он поможет другим.